# Implement unit test for sending contact mails

Tags: symfony

I have a contact controller which render my contact form and validate the request. After validation success the contact controller create a Contactobject and call the method proceedContact from ContactHandler. Now i would like to write a phpunit test for my handler. It's my first unit test. I have following questions.

- Should I test my controller or is it sufficient if I test only the handler.?
- How can i inject the services into my Contacthandler?
- How can i check if the mailer send the email successful?
- Exists an similar example for this use case?

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\Utils;

  use AppBundle\Entity\Contact;

  class ContactHandler
  {
  private $mailer;
  private $templating;
  private $translator;
  private $emailTo;
  private $emailCc;

  public function __construct($mailer, $templating, $translator, $emailTo, $emailCc)
  {
      $this->mailer = $mailer;
      $this->templating = $templating;
      $this->translator = $translator;
      $this->emailTo = $emailTo;
      $this->emailCc = $emailCc;
  }

  public function proceedContact(Contact $contact)
  { 
      $subject_part_1 = $this->translator->trans('contact_mail_subject');
      $subject_part_2 = $this->translator->trans($contact->getRequest());
      $subject = $subject_part_1 . ' - ' . $subject_part_2;

      $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
          ->setSubject($subject)
          ->setFrom($contact->getEmail())
          ->setTo($this->emailTo)
          ->setCc($this->emailCc)
          ->setBody(
              $this->templating->render(
              'Emails/contact.html.twig',
              array('name' => $contact->getName(), 'message' => $contact->getMessage())
          ),
          'text/html'
      );

      $this->mailer->send($message);
  }


  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logic (email sending) should not be done in an Entity.

You should create a service instead, or create a method in the corresponding controller.

Also, when the architecture of your logic is ok, to deal with the service container in your tests, see [the corresponding part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#accessing-the-container) of the documentation.

See also [this very good article about using Dependency Injection in tests](http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/08/unit-test-your-symfony2-bundle-di-like-a-boss/).

And, to send e-mail from your tests (more functional than unit in this case), see [E-mail testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html).

Try to use this informations to build your test, and if you encounter difficulties, ask a precise question for a precise problem here.